# How to set empty data text in a groupable kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having a `groupable kendo grid`.

Please help me out with setting some custom text whenever the grid is empty.

If grid is not groupable i could acheive it using databound funtion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a version I adapted from KendoGridBinderEx as I wanted a function on databound that could handle not only empty but error cases too. I've modified it back to mostly suit what you're struggling with. When my datasource has errors I'll read them out of the event that I pass into the function itself, thus why you see 'e' referenced as a parameter but not used.

```
function DisplayNoResultsFound(evt) {
    var grid = evt.sender.element;
    //Only do this if you can properly find the grid
    if (grid.data("kendoGrid") == undefined) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the number of Columns in the grid
    var dataSource = grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    var colCount = grid.find('.k-grid-header colgroup > col').length;

    //Check for an empty datasource
    if (dataSource._view.length == 0) {
        //Clear the grid 
        //you may or may not need this depending on how your datasource returns
        grid.find('.k-grid-content tbody').empty();

        //Add the no result row
        grid.find('.k-grid-content tbody')
        .append('<tr class="kendo-data-row"><td colspan="' + colCount + '" style="text-align:center" class="k-state-error"><b>No Results Found</b></td></tr>');
    }

    // Get visible row count
    var rowCount = grid.find('.k-grid-content tbody tr').length;

    // If the row count is less that the page size add in the number of missing rows
    if (rowCount < dataSource._take) {
        var addRows = dataSource._take - rowCount;
        for (var i = 0; i < addRows; i++) {
            grid.find('.k-grid-content tbody').append('<tr class="kendo-data-row"><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>');
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sparksterz/jd1ujvt8/)

Comment: Thanks for the response. But this one also not working incase of groupable kendo grid :/ . Working fine for a not groupable kendo grid. Can you please share JSFiddle.?

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle which points to a server side Kendo OData source. If you try and filter Order ID = 0 you should get "No Results Found", similarly if you add any number of groups you should still see the message.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian. That is working fine. but what I wanted is a groupable kendo grid which looks like this : 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/grid6_1.png
This is grouping according to the last name.
I am having trouble in adding "empty text" for this kind of a grid. :(

Comment: can you please modify the fiddle according to this scenerio.? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand how I haven't done exactly what you're trying to do...

I did an update to the JSFiddle which applies the filter and the group for you: http://jsfiddle.net/sparksterz/jd1ujvt8/1/

Is that not what you're trying to do?